# how to pass git repository credentials in gradle - build.gradle

Tags: java, git, gradle

We have a gradle project and we want to get few dependencies from git repository. We are passing git URL (settings.gradle) and username and password(inside build.gradle). build.gradle has following to pass username and password:

authentication(userName: 'username', password: 'password')

> **Could not find method authentication() for arguments [{userName=mavenUser, 
>         password=mavenPassword}] on root project 'project-name' of type org.gradle.api.Project.**

if we remove above authentication from gradle.properties , we are getting following exception:

org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException:  : Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered

Gradle version is 2.1, whereas git repository is hosted on secure server and repository added as :

```
'''project.dependencies {
    implementation "com.abc.ds.base:common"
   }'''
```

above module git repository 'common' is not having any SSH key and private key set. But to access git we are using username and password.

Comment: Enter username and passoword in gradle.properties.

Comment: You shouldn't put auth credentials in a gradle file... You should inject them as properties that will be read... For example, read these creds from the "environment property username and pwd" , and then set these properties in the environment on the machine that runs this code